# matlab while loop multiple conditions

Tags: matlab, while-loop, operators, conditional-statements

Hi programming in Matlab here, and for some reason I keep getting errors in my while loop. Can anyone give me an example on how to make multiple conditions in a while loop? Here is my while loop,

```
while (user_input ~= 256);%try catch does not work very well for this
 prompt = 'Please enter one of the listed gray levels (256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2). ';
 user_input = input(prompt);
end
```

I would like it to be something like ,

```
while (user_input ~= 256 || user_input ~= 128 || user_input ~= 64)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol `&` is the `and` logical operator. You can use it for multiple conditions in your `while` loop.

```
while (user_input ~= 256 & user_input ~= 128 & user_input ~= 64)
    prompt = 'Please enter one of the listed gray levels (256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2). ';
    user_input = input(prompt);
end
```

As beaker pointed out, what you ask is to ask for input as long as it is not one of the following values : 256, 128 or 64. Using the `or` logical operator would mean that `user_input` should be 256, 128 and 64 at the same time to break the loop.

---

You can also use [`ismember`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html).

```
conditional_values = [256, 128 , 64]
while ~ismember(user_input, conditional_values)
    prompt = 'Please enter one of the listed gray levels (256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2). ';
    user_input = input(prompt);
end
```

---

An other way to go, proposed by Luis Mendo, is to use [`any`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html)

```
conditional_values = [256, 128 , 64]
while ~any(user_input==conditional values)
    prompt = 'Please enter one of the listed gray levels (256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2). ';
    user_input = input(prompt);
end
```

`user_input == conditional_value` returns an array composed of 1s and 0s depending on if values of `conditional_values` match with `user_input`. Then any finds if there is at least one `1` on this array. Then we apply `~` which is the `not` operator.

Comment: I'd go with `ismember` indeed. +1

Comment: The condition is always satisfied. If `user_input == 256` then `user_input ~= 128` and `user_input ~= 64`. I suspect the OP wants `&`.

Comment: Or, perhaps simpler, `while ~any(user_input==conditional values)`

Comment: ismemeber seems like the best way since I need something that will act as if it were an ||, not an &&. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @bobdude "I need something that will act as if it were an ||, not an &&"... Not according to your conditions. If you use `||` you're going to continue looping if your value is not equal to *any* of the comparison values. You've created an infinite loop since a single value can't be equal to all of them.

Comment: @bobdude I realized that my comment could be ambiguous, so I'm going to try to clarify. If you use `|`, the loop will only terminate when `user_input` is equal to **all** of the given values, **256**, **128** and **64**. Since no number can be equal to all of these at the same time, you will never exit the loop.